# Inject filter into Zend_View

Tags: php, zend-framework, dependency-injection, zend-view, zend-filter

I wish to set some properties in `MyFilter` with constructor injection but it seems impossible with `Zend_View::addFilter(string $filter_class_name)` since it loads a new instance upon usage. `MyFilter` implements `Zend_Filter_Interface`.

Can I somehow inject *an instance* of a filter to an instance of `Zend_View`?

Closing since it (hopefully) will be pushed into 2.0, see [ticket on JIRA](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9718).

Comment: I was thinking about using something like `Zend_View::getFilter()` but that method works just like `::setFilter()`.. no luck there.

Comment: Eh, seems I can't find any good reasons to vote for closing. Abandon ship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't in the 1.x branch, ticket is filed:

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9718

Answer (score 0):

You may pass object:

```
$filter = new Your_Filter($params); // implements Zend_Filter_Interface
$view->addFilter($filter);
```

You may get view instance from viewRenderer, e.g. using staticHelper.

Edit:

The other method may be:

```
class MyFilterSetup extends MyFilter implements Zend_Filter_Interface 
{
     public function __construct($params)
     {
           $this->_params = $params;
           parent::__construct();
     }

     public function filter($string)
     {
         // .... $this->_params;
     }
}
```

Comment: Your code is invalid. `Zend_View::addFilter()` takes a string (or array of strings) as argument and loads the classes dynamically later. If you in fact can get your code to run, feel free to write some more lines of code to cover it :) Thanks.

Comment: The new code example works like the first, still no chance to actually get a value into it before it's used inside Zend_View.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I don't think it's possible. Looking at the sourcecode `setFilter()` and `addFilter()` only accept the Filter Classname as a string. You cannot set any options, like you can in `Zend_Form` for instance. What you could do though is:

```
class MyFilter implements Zend_Filter_Interface 
{
     protected static $_config;
     public static setConfig(array $options)
     {
         self::_config = $options;
     }
     // ... do something with the options
}
```

and then you set the options where needed with `MyFilter::setOptions()`, so when `Zend_View` instantiates the Filter instance, it got what it needs to properly run the filter.

Comment: That is nearly one option but not very elegant. What if I would want to add the same filter twice, but with different settings?

Comment: @chelmertz Then you likely would have to customize `Zend_View` to do what you want to do. Or store the number of instantiations the filter went through as another static property and add one config per instance statically. That ain't pretty, but would work.

Comment: I'd rather use the output of `Zend_View::render()` and apply a filter on that, but it takes away the power of having associated fitlers with the view. Gonna push this further if there isn't something we've missed.

Answer (score 0):

Can't we create a custom view object extending `Zend_View` that overrides the `addFilter()` method to accept either a class or an instance. Then override the `_filter()` method to deal with both types of filters - string and instance - that we have stored.

Comment: I think there's a design error and that those should be revised within the framework in itself. But I think it's a valid solution so.. why not patch it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not assign the filter properties to the view, and then either set the properties when the view is set, or access the view directly in your filtering function? e.g.

```
$view->assign('MyFilterProperty', 'fubar');
```

and then in your filter class:

```
public function setView($aView)
{
    $this->_property = $aView->MyFilterPropery;
}
```

It's kludgy, but it should get the job done.

Comment: I do not think this approach would work because 1) the filter would depend (or hijack) each property, and; 2) it does not filter all of the output. Imagine I'd like to apply a filter invoking `str_replace()`-functionality on the regular rendering of the view, in two sequential calls, with different parameters (sorry for a dumb example:)